# A PHP Function to Convert ALL CAPS Paragraph String to Regular Case?

Tags: php, optimization, string, performance

I'm on the hunt for a speedy function that will receive a string as a parameter and take this input:

```
LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. SUSPENDISSE ET QUAM
EU LACUS SCELERISQUE GRAVIDA. DONEC PELLENTESQUE DICTUM DOLOR VEL PULVINAR.
NUNC RHONCUS, ERAT EU SUSCIPIT ALIQUET, RISUS NUNC DICTUM MAGNA, AC ALIQUAM
NIBH NULLA EGET DOLOR. SUSPENDISSE POTENTI. MAECENAS ULLAMCORPER DIAM NON URNA
VEHICULA ET ULTRICIES TURPIS INTERDUM. PHASELLUS INTERDUM MAGNA ET EROS CURSUS
TRISTIQUE.
```

And return this output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et quam
eu lacus scelerisque gravida. Donec pellentesque dictum dolor vel pulvinar.
Nunc rhoncus, erat eu suscipit aliquet, risus nunc dictum magna, ac aliquam
nibh nulla eget dolor. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas ullamcorper diam non urna
vehicula et ultricies turpis interdum. Phasellus interdum magna et eros cursus
tristique.
```

Anyone know of an existing one? Trying to not recreate the wheel if I don't have to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, this comes to mind:

```
$sentences = array_map('ucfirst',
             array_map('trim',
             array_map('strtolower', explode('.', $input))));
$output = implode('. ', $sentences).'.';
```

Not fool proof or terribly efficient, but it will get you 98% of the way. You can roll (parts of) your own as you see fit, trading effort for customization/efficiency.

**Update:** The original answer had a bug: `explode` left a space at the start of each line, which then had `ucfirst` fail because the first character was a space. Added `trim` to the mix to fix that and also make it "more correct".

I also added a trailing `.` to the output.

Comment: The output's going to need a `.` appended to the end, but I suppose that falls in the 2%.

Comment: @Wooble: Good catch, revised to cover that.

Comment: Neither ucfirst nor strtolower are Unicode-Save. Replace strtolower with mb_strtolower and ucfirst with mb_convert_case(trim($input), MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8');

Comment: @Benjamin: Upvoted the comment to make it more visible, but it depends on what the charset is. Only @Kirk knows that, so he can modify as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, right from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php):

```
function ucfirst_sentence($str)
{
    return preg_replace('/\b(\w)/e', 'strtoupper("$1")', $str);
}

$text = strtowlower($initialText);
echo ucfirst_sentence($text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [strotolower($string)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php);

**Disregard, didn't see you needed sentence casing.**

Be careful with this though, as not all periods *should* have an uppercase letter after them (eg pauses ...), or you may possibly convert names/proper nouns etc to lowercase.

Comment: This will make the complete string lowercase, which is not what he wants.

Comment: Ah yes I see the uppercase words :/